# Как получить android apk с bitbucket CI

Tags: android-studio, bitbucket, непрерывная-интеграция

Как получить android apk с bitbucket CI?

```
- curl -X POST "https://${BB_AUTH_STRING}@api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/${BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER}/${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}/downloads" --form files=@"app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить `*.apk` в slack.

Добавить переменные в репозиторий на bitbucket `Settings -> Environment variables`:
`SLACK_TOKEN` - получить можно тут [api.slack.com](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens)
`SLACK_CHANNEL` - название канала в slack

Добавить в файл сборки `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` строку:

```
- curl -F file=@"./app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk" -F channels=${SLACK_CHANNEL} -F token=${SLACK_TOKEN} https://slack.com/api/files.upload
```